# httpUploadProgress and putObject with AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, progress

I have an applicaiot to upload files to Amazon S3(aws sdk) with javascript. The app is uplaoding the files to S3. I tried to add the httpUploadProgress event to control the progress of the uploaded file, the file is in S3, but the progress percentage never appear. This is my code.

```
bucket.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
}
}).on('httpUploadProgress',function(progress) {
console.log(Math.round(progress.loaded/progress.total*100)+ '% done');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
Greetings

Comment: please show the initialise code and 'params'.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can checkout [the github link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/084f676927b9cd3da337bd6d0d230680c138d73b) for the information. Also i think don't use

`console.log(Math.round(progress.loaded/progress.total*100)+ '% done');`

just use

`console.log(progress.loaded + " of " + progress.total + " bytes");`

You can use sample code from the git hub page

```
var request = s3.putObject(params);
request.on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {
  console.log(progress.loaded + " of " + progress.total + " bytes");
});
request.send();
```

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for your help. I found the answer.
I updated the was library to the latest version